# How can i change yacc to bison (LFS)

Tags: linux, bison, yacc, linux-from-scratch

I'm currently working on LFS, and have to change yacc to bison.
I have tried to install bison, but it did not change anything.
this is what i have : `/usr/bin/yacc -> /etc/alternatives/yacc`
and this is what i need `/usr/bin/yacc -> /etc/alternatives/bison`

Comment: Are you asking how to replace one symlink with another? `ln -sf`, but that's not really a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

The recommendation from LFS is to create a wrapper:

```
cat > /usr/bin/yacc << "EOF"
#!/bin/sh
# Begin /usr/bin/yacc

/usr/bin/bison -y $*

# End /usr/bin/yacc
EOF
chmod 755 /usr/bin/yacc
```

Please see their instructions for details: [install bison](http://archive.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs-museum/2.4.3/LFS-BOOK-INTEL-2.4.3-HTML/ch06-bison.html)

Comment: if this addresses your question, please consider marking answered.

Comment: How do I do that?